# Flutter firebase phone sign in needs a hot restart to be authenticated

Tags: firebase, authentication, dart, flutter, email

My app has an email and phone sign up, for email once i sign in with the right information i get transferred directly to the homepage, however when i sign in with my phone authentication, it would take me back to the auth page and only lets me into the homepage if i hot restart, i even tried to navigate directly to the homepage once the auth is complete but i dont seem to recognize that i signed in until i hot restart, any idea how i can handle this?

authentication code:

```
String phoneNo;
String smsCode;
  String verificationId;
  String uid;

  Future<void> verifyPhone() async {
    final PhoneCodeAutoRetrievalTimeout autoRetrieve = (String verId) {
      this.verificationId = verId;
};

final PhoneCodeSent smsCodeSent = (String verId, [int forceCodeResend]) {
  this.verificationId = verId;
  smsCodeDialog(context).then((value) {
    print('Signed in');
  });
};

final PhoneVerificationCompleted verifiedSuccess = (FirebaseUser user) {
  print('verified');
};

final PhoneVerificationFailed veriFailed = (AuthException exception) {
  print('${exception.message}');
};

await FirebaseAuth.instance.verifyPhoneNumber(
    phoneNumber: this.phoneNo,
    codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: autoRetrieve,
    codeSent: smsCodeSent,
    timeout: const Duration(seconds: 5),
    verificationCompleted: verifiedSuccess,
    verificationFailed: veriFailed);
  }

  Future<bool> smsCodeDialog(BuildContext context) {
    return showDialog(
    context: context,
    barrierDismissible: false,
    builder: (BuildContext context) {
      return new AlertDialog(
        title: Text('Enter sms Code'),
        content: TextField(
          onChanged: (value) {
            this.smsCode = value;
          },
        ),
        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
        actions: <Widget>[
          new FlatButton(
            child: Text('Done'),
            onPressed: () {
              FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser().then((user) {
                if (user != null) {
                  setState(() {
                    this.uid = user.uid;
                    _submitForm(widget.model.authenticate, 2);

                    Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('/');
                  });
                } else {
                  Navigator.of(context).pop();
                  signIn();
                }
              });
            },
          )
        ],
      );
    });
  }

  signIn() async {
    _submitForm(widget.model.authenticate, 2);
  }}
  void _submitForm(Function authenticate, int option) async {if(option == 2) {
  Map<String, dynamic> successInformation;
  successInformation = await authenticate(
      null, phoneNo, null, tokenValue, uid, verificationId, smsCode);
  if (successInformation['success']) {
    Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/');
  }} else{

 Map<String, dynamic> successInformation;
  successInformation = await authenticate(_formData['Email'], null,
      _formData['Password'], tokenValue, null, null, null, _authMode);
  if (successInformation['success']) {
    print('success');
    Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/');
  } }

Future<Map<String, dynamic>> authenticate(
  String email,
  String phone,
  String password,
  String token,
  String id,
  String verificationId,
  String smsCode,
  [AuthMode mode = AuthMode.Login]) async {
_isLoading = true;
notifyListeners();
String uid;
final Map<String, dynamic> authData = {
  'email': email,
  'password': password,
  'returnSecureToken': true,
};
if (email != null) {
  try {
    FirebaseUser user = await FirebaseAuth.instance
        .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);
    uid = user.uid;
  } catch (error) {
    _isLoading = false;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}  else {
  FirebaseUser user = await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithPhoneNumber(
      verificationId: verificationId, smsCode: smsCode);
  print(user);
  uid = user.uid;
}
_authenticatedUser =
    User(id: uid, phone: phone, email: email, token: token);
setAuthTimeout(int.parse(1000.toString()));
_userSubject.add(true);
email == null
    ? addTokenPhone(token, _authenticatedUser.phone, uid)
    : addToken(token, _authenticatedUser.email, uid);
final DateTime now = DateTime.now();
final DateTime expiryTime =
    now.add(Duration(seconds: int.parse(10000.toString())));
SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
prefs.setString('token', uid);
prefs.setString('userEmail', email);
prefs.setString('phone', phone);
prefs.setString('userId', uid);
prefs.setString('expiryTime', expiryTime.toIso8601String());
_isLoading = false;

notifyListeners();
return {
  'success': true,
  'message': 'message',
};
}
void autoAuthenticate() async {
final SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
final String token = prefs.getString('token');
final String expiryTimeString = prefs.getString('expiryTime');
if (token != null) {
  final DateTime now = DateTime.now();
  final parsedExpiryTime = DateTime.parse(expiryTimeString);
  if (!verified) {
    if (parsedExpiryTime.isBefore(now)) {
      _authenticatedUser = null;
      notifyListeners();
      return;
    }
  }
  final String userEmail = prefs.getString('userEmail');
  final String phone = prefs.getString('phone');
  final String userId = prefs.getString('userId');
  final int tokenLifespan = parsedExpiryTime.difference(now).inSeconds;
  _authenticatedUser =
      User(id: userId, email: userEmail, phone: phone, token: token);
  print(_authenticatedUser);
  _userSubject.add(true);
  setAuthTimeout(tokenLifespan);
  notifyListeners();
}
}
```

And my homepage has this initstate:

```
 bool _isAuthenticated = false;

@override
void initState() {
_model.autoAuthenticate();
_model.userSubject.listen(
  (bool isAuthenticated) {
    setState(
      () {
        _isAuthenticated = isAuthenticated;
      },
    );
  },
);
super.initState();
}
```

and the route is setup like this:

```
'/': (BuildContext context) =>
          !_isAuthenticated ? AuthPage() : HomePage(),
```

Comment: I don't know much about flutter but this plugin I use might give you some ideas, basically you can run an function to check if the phones required permissions for the app devices such as camera is correct https://github.com/NeoLSN/cordova-plugin-android-permissions

Answer (score 0):

I just made sure to call this, in every method that needed an id:

```
    FirebaseUser user = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
```

and get the id and everything for the user.